# Logical Constraints : How to express symmetry in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, logic, constraints, graph-theory

I've got a logical problem, I find some expression of what I want, but for now I'm overconstrainted and I don't know how to relax it.

---

### The Context:

Let's assume we've got an oriented graph which can have cycles. There is no weight on edges. So something really simple as follow  (don't bother with what is inside each node, it is not important) :

[image: Example of graph (Kripke Model)]

One important thing : *w1* is never changing his name.

---

### The Problem:

I'm formalizing logical problem with graph. To tell that there is an edge between the node *wi* and the node *wj* : I have got a propositional variable (which can be true or false) named *Rij*. So for N nodes, I've got N^2 propositional variables.

Theses graphs have [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism), and I would like to formalize the constraints 
that if there is no edge between *i* and *j* then there is no edge between *i* and *k* (for *k* > *j*).

Say with others words, I want to put constraints to formalize the breaking of symmetry in graphs.

I try something naïve as follow :

```
forall i, forall j (>i), forall k (>j), ( not(Rij) --> not(Rik) )
```

This constraint is working quite often, unfortunately, it's over constraining. It happens sometimes that we can't put any label of nodes in order to respect theses constraints;

example of problem:
   [image]

With this example, it is impossible to name A,B,C such as if there is no edge between *wi* and *wj* then there is no edge between *wi* and *wk* (with k>j).

---

### Sum-up of the problem

There is a way to adapt theses logicals constraints (or to formulate totally new ones) in order than we can always rename A,B,C... in one and only one way, no matter the original graph. My problem: how to formulate theses constraints ?

---

Thanks in advance for your help !

Best Regards.